# How to fix "Cannot find module './<image_name>.jpg'" when loading images in React app

Tags: reactjs, image, require

I am trying to display images that are in my public folder of my react app in the compnents and use require statements inside react-image tags as follows:

```
{profile.profile.picture && <Img src={require(`../../../public/profile-pictures/${profile.profile.picture}`)} alt=""/>}
```

I keep getting the above mentioned module not found error despite the image being present exactly where it should be. I tried a lot of solutions on SO but none of them seem to work for me. What could the error be?

Also I am new to React and am absolutely lost on what exactly is webpack and where do I even find this webpack.config.js file (if it exists for my app)

Comment: I am also getting the same error when i am building a variable name using require? When i load the img with <img src={require(`${varname}`)}/> i get Wepack Errror Cannot find module './imagename.jpg' . Were you able to fix this issue? This is happening while using url-loader. The image gets uploaded on server and i get 200 response with the imagename and imagepath back from the server. Still cant see the image on client side after the image upload. Please help.